# Resolve "connection reset by peer" issue when storing json dumped string using python client in Redis 2.4.8

Tags: python, json, redis, connection-reset

Environments: Ubuntu 10.04 64bit, Python Redis client 2.4.1, Redis
2.4.8, Python 2.6.5

Problem description:

I have some big Python dictionaries (key1:value1, key2:value2, ...).
Each key is a short string, and each value is a simplejson dumped long
string. I'd like to store dictionaries into different redis databases,
I used the following code: "r.mset(the_dictionary)". It works for one
dictionary, however, for another one, it prompts with "connection
reset by peer" error. I am pretty sure the dictionaries are of the
same format. I felt it strange to have such a fatal error.

Additionally, I have tried the following steps to identify the problem
source:

1. I separately insert each dictionary into Redis from flushed
   database (one new service for each dictionary). I still got the first
   dictionary insertion worked and the second failed.
2. I suspect the problem is from the internal of second dictionary,
   so I tried to do some variable type and string length checks, all keys
   and values passed the simple check. But I still have the storage of
   second dictionary failed.
3. If I change the dictionary values to the same constant variable
   (e.g. all values are set to "abc"), then the storage works.
4. If I use r.hmset for each key and value in the second pairs, it
   works as well.

But why "r.mset(the_dictionry)" can work for one dictionary, but fail
in another?

There must be something wrong in the values of dictionary or some bugs
in the Python client.

I don't know how can I proceed to identify the problem source. Please
give me some suggestions.

I searched google and tried redis server log, but still cannot get it
through.

======Response to feedback======
Here is the code snippet:

```
db3 = redis.Redis(db=2)
db3.flushdb()
db3.mset(oov_dist_dict)
```

But if I follow feedback to split the dictionary and insert to redis, It works, Could you please explain it a little bit? I didn't see any statements in the official documents.

Comment: Could you create a small script that shows the problem?

Comment: I would say it is linked to the size of the command sent to Redis. Try to cut the dictionary in separate pieces and pipeline many small MSET commands to Redis.